# How to define overlapping hopping windows in Esper using EPL?

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

How can I define an overlapping tumbling window as EPL query in Esper? I'm looking for equivalent of hopping windows similar to these:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/hopping-window-azure-stream-analytics

For example: 1 second hopping window with 500ms overlap.

Esper's reference manual describes [tumbling windows](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html/epl-views.html) and overlapping context, but how can I express it as a query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the overlapping context. Things that fire regularly are done with a pattern.

```
create context Hopping 
  initiated by pattern[every timer:interval(500 milliseconds)]
  terminated after 1 second;
context Hopping select sum(price) from StockTick output when terminated;
```